# Attempt to invoke virtual method addView on null reference object even though object is referenced

Tags: java, android

In my class, I have created a variable...

```
private ImageView imgLayoutImgEditPet;
```

In the `onCreate` method, I reference the variable...

```
imgLayoutImgEditPet = new ImageView(this);
```

I then add this `ImageView` to the layout...

```
layoutImgEditPet.addView(imgLayoutImgEditPet);
```

This should work, yet I get this error...

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

How can I instantiate a new `ImageView` to my layout?

Comment: It's not the `ImageView`. It's `layoutImgEditPet` that's null.

Comment: layoutImgEditPet is still referenced, but it is in <include> tag. How would i reference the layout if it's in the include tags?

Comment: You'd `findViewById()` it just like you would any other `View`. However, if it's the root `View` in the included layout, and you've set an `android:id` on the `<include>` tag, be aware that the `<include>`'s ID overrides the root `View`'s ID. That is, the root `View` will end up with the ID that's on the `<include>`.

Comment: ahh gotcha. i will have to reference the included layout and find its inner layout by using includedlayout.innerlayout.findViewById()

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. I'm just pointing out that the root `View`'s ID might not be what you expect. After it's attached to the `Activity`'s hierarchy, you can just use `findViewById()` directly, like any other `View`, no matter how nested it is, but you have to use the correct ID.

Comment: Oooooooh. I guess I will have to nest the linearlayout of the included layout inside another layout because the linear layout i was trying to reference is in fact the root view

Comment: That's fine. You don't have to nest it. Just use the right ID to find it. If you have an `android:id` on the `<include>` tag, then that's the ID that the `LinearLayout` will end up with, no matter what ID you've set on the `<LinearLayout>` tag.

Comment: Ahh. Got it! It's working now. Thanks!